# How do I create stretch-auto-auto column layout in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

so basically I want something like this:

[image: screen]

Is it possible to achieve this with columns instead of floats?

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div class="float-left"><button class="rounded btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Expand All</button></div>
   <div class="float-right">
      <nav aria-label="...">
         <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">&lt;</a></li>
            <li class="page-item active bg-dark"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">&gt;</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <div class="float-right"><span>2 Results</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **flexbox** which is included in Bootstrap 4. The only "trick" used here is `ml-auto` (margin-left:auto) on the middle DIV so that it gets pushed to the right. Use `order-` to change the order of DIV's.

https://www.codeply.com/go/ayBOamHipS

```
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div>
            <button class="rounded btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Expand All</button>
        </div>
        <div class="order-last"> 
            <nav aria-label="...">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">&lt;</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item active bg-dark"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">&gt;</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto py-2"> <span>2 Results </span> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why would I use order-* instead of reordering the the divs itself?

Comment: You can do that too. I wasn't sure if you had reason for that order other than the floats.